# Adding multiple content type in restclient headers

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I am trying to post two types of data to the api. "multipart/form-data" and "application/json".

This is the headers and payload I am passing:

```
payload = {
  :multipart => true,
  :user_photo => File.open(file_path),
  :id_photo => File.open('file_path'),
  :type => 'face_match'
  }

headers =  { "Content-Type" => "multipart/form-data","accessToken" => NIL }
data = JSON RestClient.post(api_endpoint + url, payload, headers)
```

How can I pass two content types in headers? I am using Ruby and rest-client.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP only allows one `Content-Type` header, and the `Content-Type` header can only have one value. What you want is impossible, because HTTP doesn't support it. There's nothing Ruby or rest-client can do about that.